# NSCombobox binding issues

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsarraycontroller, nscombobox

I wish I could select the area of risk from NSCombobox "A" and then automatically its "fee" should appear in cell "B". This is because I'll have to multiply the "Surface" and "rate".

Column "A" binding:
Value
bind to: Particelle
controller key: arrangedObjects
model key path: nome.

NSCombobox binding:
Content
bind to: Area Rischio
controller key: arrangedObjects

Content Values
bind to: arrangedObjects
model key path: nome
[image]
[image]
With this set up the combobox shows me are the area of risk included and once selected the area of ​​risk desired recording. Now I would like once you have selected the area of ​​risk appeared the fee in the field beside it.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options:

- bind the column of the Tariffa field to the same property as Area di Rischio. Add a value transformer that would retrieve the correct value.
- use the representedObject on the row and navigate to the value you want via the key paths.

It looks me me like both the name and the tariff are two representation of a tariff. So keypath or value transformer should get you what you want.

Comment: Hello, I am several weeks I'm stuck on this problem and you're the only one who has tried to help me. I tried your suggestion, but it did not work. Probably because I'm no expert. Let me ask you, if possible, in if you were willing to take a look at my project. Can I send it? Thank you.